# python ignoring if statement in grade calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
def midterm_1(): 

    print("Midterm 1:")
    weight_1=int(input("Weight 0-100?"))
    score_earned=int(input("Score earned?"))
    score_shift=int(input("Were scores shifted (1=yes 2=no)?"))
    if  (score_shift==1):
        shift_amount=int(input("What was the shift amount?"))
        score_earned=int(shift_amount)+int(score_earned)
    if (score_earned >100):
        score_earned=100
    print("Total points = "+str(score_earned)+str("/100"))
    weighted_score=int((score_earned/100)*weight_1)
    print("Your weighted score = "+str(weighted_score)+"/"+str(weight_1))
```

This code is supposed to be apart of a larger code to compute grade. When the weighted score is printed it only regards score_earned as a 100 or 0.

How should I fix this?

Here is an example output when there is not score shift:

```
Midterm 1:
Weight 0-100? 50
Score earned? 78
Were scores shifted (1=yes 2=no)? 2
Total points = 78/100
Your weighted score = 0/50
```

When there is a score shift and score_earned is over 100:

```
Midterm 1:
Weight 0-100? 89
Score earned? 89
Were scores shifted (1=yes 2=no)? 1
What was the shift amount? 90
Total points = 100/100
Your weighted score = 89/89
```

Comment: Please supply a [mcve]. In this instance, specify *exactly* what inputs you are entering, what you *see* as the output and what you *expect* as the output.

Comment: Your code works fine in Python 3, but fails in Python 2.7 (because of the integer division on the second last line). Are you sure you use 3.x?

Comment: Also, what makes you think Python is "ignoring if statement"? Which `if` do you think it's ignoring, and why? I can't see how ignoring either `if` could lead to the problem you described in the text.

Comment: I think it is only recognizing the  if score_earned>100 because that is the only time my program is correct. Otherwise, it just sets score_earned=0

Comment: But your text says it works when the score is 100, and 100 > 100 is not true.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are not using Python 3.x; you are using 2.7 - your results can be reproduced only in 2.7, but not in 3.x.

Second, you have integer division in the line

```
weighted_score = int((score_earned / 100) * weight_1)
```

In Python 2.7, if you divide a smaller int number by a larger int number, you always get a 0. Your line must be:

```
weighted_score = int((score_earned / 100.0) * weight_1) # Mind the .0
```

Answer (score 0):

you should really take a step back and look at the parts of your problem

1. First you need to get some integer input that is between some values

something like this

```
def get_integer(prompt,min_val=float("-inf"),max_val=float("inf")):
    while True:
        try:
           result = int(input(prompt))
        except (TypeError,ValueError):
           print("That is not an integer... try again")
           continue
        else:
           if min_val < result < max_val: 
              return result # guaranteed to be an integer
           print("Please Enter a value Between {min_val} - {max_val}".format(min_val=min_val,max_val=max_val))
```

2. next you need to get 3 fields from a user lets make a helper function

something like this

```
def get_input(exam_name):
    """ guaranteed to return 3 integers between 0 and 100 """
    print("Enter Scores For : {exam}".format(exam=exam_name))
    return get_integer("Weight:",0,100),get_integer("Score:",0,100),get_integer("Offset(or zero for none):",0,100)
```

3. finally just use your helper functions to get individual values

something like

```
def midterm1():
   wt,score,offset = get_input("Midterm 1")
   score = min(score+offset,100) # if score + offset > 100 then just use 100
   return wt,score
```

but none of these points actually address your question .... which is addressed in @dyz answer